# LibFM sparse data format

Tags: sparse

Does the order of columns in the the sparse format matters in case of libfm ? Can I list the non zero components of X in libfm in any order in a row.

Comment: If your question is solely about a software (and not about statistics), then this site is not the right place to ask. Have you taken a look at Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says that libFM uses the LIBSVM file format. LIBSVM provides a python tool to validate data files, and that tool throws an error if the column indices are not in ascending order:

https://github.com/tomz/libsvm-ruby-swig/blob/master/libsvm-3.1/tools/checkdata.py#L87

So I would assume that for libFM the column indices should also be in ascending order.